# Changing who "shares" a google document when using addCommenter()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets-api

**Context/Background**: I have a google form that generates a mail merged style document using the data captured from the form. The form embeds the generated document as a url inside of the a sheet. In the sheet I have a script that iterates over the rows and uses the [`addCommenter(user)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addCommenter(User)) to "share" the generated document. All of this works as expected.

**Issue** When the document sends, it arrives in the user's inbox as
.

> **MyFirstName MylastName** has invited you to comment on the following document:

Where *MyFirstName* and *MyLastName* is my real first and last from my google profile. 
Also, this occurs when another user is using the form and sheet as a collaborator/editor, rather than the actual user who is using the form. Clearly not the default behavior, but that is my intention.

**What I attempted** 
To do to try and fix the issue, I thought to change the "owner" of the the document to the user who is using the form. This was accomplished by setting the form to capture email addresses and then using the following lines in my script.

```
  file.setOwner(formUserEmail);
  file.addCommenter(recipientEmail);
```

But this did not resolve the issue. The sent email still went out as me. Is there a way to change who "shares" the document when using   [`addCommenter(user)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addCommenter(User)) ?

**Testing/More info/clarification for comments**
Let me be UserA, and let another person be UserB.

1. UserA, being the person the owns

   - The Google Form
   - The Spreadsheet capturing the data behind the form
   - The Script running behind the Spreadsheet who is calling [`addCommenter(user)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addCommenter(User))
2. UserB, being

   - The A Contributor added to UserA's Google Form
   - The A Editor added to UserA's Spreadsheet capturing the data behind the form
   - The (I am assuming permission of the script is inherited from the parent spreadsheet) Script running behind the Spreadsheet who is calling [`addCommenter(user)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addCommenter(User))

According to my testing. When I logged in as UserB, as a contributor to User A's google form, and as an editor of the attached spreadsheet owned by User A. I was able to run submit data as UserB, but the script ran under User A's Auth* and therefore sent the email share message as user A. To reframe my question, what is the best way to ensure that UserB's Auth is used given the context mentioned above? I am assuming the only option is to let User B make a copy of the system then they will use their auth? I would prefer to find a way to programmatically add userB to this system.

Comment: The script that adds the commenter using `addCommenter(user)` is run by you (or runs under your authorization), hence you are giving access to the document to the `user`. The only have to change that behavior is to have the users run that script under there authorization.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question. Do you want to change who sends the email, or change who owns the document? Or both?

Comment: @JasonAllshorn Good point. It really doesn't matter (for all three cases) so long as the message `MyFirstName MylastName has invited you to comment on the following document:` has the name of the person using the form is the person sharing the document.

Comment: @JasonAllshorn. Just to clarify. Let me be UserA, and let another person be UserB.  According to my testing. When I logged in as UserB, as a contributor to User A's google form, and as an editor of the attached spreadsheet owned by User A.  I was able to run submit data as UserB, but **the script ran under User A's Auth*** and therefore sent the email share message as user A. To reframe my question, what is the best way to ensure that UserB's Auth is used given the context mentioned above? I am assuming the only option is to let User B make a copy of the system then they will use their auth?

Comment: In the apps script there is an option to decide who the script runs as. At the moment it is set to run as you. You could try setting to to run as a user accessing the script.